Breakpoints Not Working With VS Code + Rust + LLDB
When debugging code using the CodeLLDB plugin in VSCode, I found that my C++ program doesn't stop at breakpoints but instead runs to completion and displays the results (on Windows). I've tried many methods to solve this issue, including checking the official documentation and forums, but to no avail. Interestingly, the same launch.json settings work fine for debugging on macOS. I also encountered the same behavior when switching to GDB for debugging. I'm unsure if this is a file or compiler issue. Do you have any suggestions?
launch.json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "lldb",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/text",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}

task.json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe 生成活动文件",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "编译器: C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe"
        },
        
    ]
}

I suspect that the debugging information might not be correctly locating the program file because more than one debugging method fails to stop at breakpoints.
